# MS SQL change Cast count VarChar to %

Tags: sql-server

In the last line of the code I have listed below, The current result is blank because the result is less than 1.  I need the results to display as a percentage but I'm not sure how.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated?

```
SELECT
 '1,*'+char(13)+char(10) 
+'80,1006058'+char(13)+char(10)
+'100,10'+char(13)+char(10)
+'2405,'+cast(count(distinct adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID) / 420 as varchar(18))+char(13)+char(10) --Census events --as varchar(10)
```

Comment: by last line do you mean `cast(count(distinct adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID) / 420 as varchar(18))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
 '1,*'+char(13)+char(10) 
+'80,1006058'+char(13)+char(10)
+'100,10'+char(13)+char(10)
+'2405,'+cast( cast(count(distinct adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID) AS FLOAT) / cast(420 AS FLOAT) as varchar(18))+char(13)+char(10) --Census events --as varchar(10)
```

You should `cast()` your numbers `as float` otherwise they are considered as `integers` and you don't have decimals in your division because the result is also considered `integer`

Comment: Never use float when doing math calculations as it is an inexact datatype and will round the answers unexpectedly. Always use decimal.

Comment: AH!  You got to cast the cast... I missed that!  My apologies and thank you for the help Thomas G / dbbri!!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your `count(distinct adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID)` returns an integer value and then you divide by 420.  Another integer.

If you cast the count distinct as a decimal or float, this should solve your issue.  `CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID) AS FLOAT)`.

Comment: Never use float when doing math calculations as it is an inexact datatype and will round the answers unexpectedly. Always use decimal.

Comment: Thanks Dbbri!

But I'm not sure I'm tracking.  Should it look like this?



    +'2405,'+cast(count(distinct adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID) as float)/ 420 as varchar(18))+char(13)+char(10)

Comment: SELECT
 '1,*'+char(13)+char(10) 
+'80,1006058'+char(13)+char(10)
+'100,10'+char(13)+char(10)
+'2405,'+cast(CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID) AS FLOAT) / 420 as varchar(18))+char(13)+char(10) --Census events --as varchar(10)

Comment: HLGEM brings up a good point.  I spent a lot of time as a consultant changing data types in an accounting system from float to decimal.  The original developer thought float would be more precise, but in the end it added and shaved pennies everywhere.  In your case, wanting a percentage based on a count, you should be fine with either.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this part

```
     cast(count(distinct adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID) / 420 as varchar(18))
```

with

```
     cast(count(distinct adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID) / 420.00 as varchar(18))
```

Note that all we did was turn 420 to 420.00 to suggest SQL to retain decimal part and not treat the result as integer.

As count return integer values and integer/integer is an integer but integer/decimal is decimal

Comment: Glad to have helped :)